# Scala, Collect double case

Tags: scala, sum, case, collect

Hi
How to transform this

for (w <- m ){
    val w = (w._2.collect { 
        case x if (x._2 > 0) => x._2;
        case x if (x._2 < 0) => x._2 }) // if I add here .sum i got sum of (negative and positive) together
  }

to get sum of positive and sum of negative values in one collect, it could be List(positive.sum,negative.sum) or two values

edit:
only groupby, slice, collect, sum and yield

I wrote working program, but it' was not acepted, beacause it doing two collect

```
val m = d.groupBy(_._1.slice(0, 7))
    for (w<- m) {
     val x = (w._2.collect { case x if (x._2>  0) =>  x._2 }).sum
     val y = (w._2.collect { case x if (x._2<  0) =>  x._2 }).sum
      println("%7s %11.2f %11.2f %11.2f" format(w._1 , x , y ,(x+y)))
    }
}
```

entry data are

val d = List(("2011-01-04", -137.76),
    ("2011-01-04", 2376.45),
    ("2011-01-04", -1.70),
    ("2011-01-04", -1.70),
    ("2011-01-04", -1.00),
    ("2011-01-06", 865.70),
    ("2011-01-07", -734.15),
    ("2011-01-05", -188.63),
    ("2011-01-06", -73.50),
    ("2011-01-07", -200.00),
    ("2011-01-09", -215.35),
    ("2011-01-09", -8.86),
    ("2011-01-09", -300.00),
    ("2011-01-11", -634.54),
    ("2011-01-11", -400.00),
    ("2011-01-12", -92.87),
    ("2011-01-13", -1839.24),
    ("2011-01-13", 10000.00),
    ("2011-01-13", -10000.00),
    ("2011-01-15", -127.97),
    ("2011-01-15", -319.02),
    ("2011-01-19", -549.00),
    ("2011-01-21", -164.80),
    ("2011-01-23", -500.00),
    ("2011-01-25", -377.97),
    ("2011-01-26", 2158.66),
    ("2011-01-26", -130.45),
    ("2011-01-27", -350.00),
    ("2011-01-29", -500.00),
    ("2011-02-01", 2376.45),
    ("2011-02-01", 955.00))

Comment: If this isn't homework, they why are the "task rules" so restrictive, and why have others asked about exactly the same problem on StackOverflow?

Comment: It was our exam, and we need to know how to solve it right, to try another term

Comment: @D4Niel - That's close enough to "homework" to belong under the homework tag.

Comment: I have one question, but if don't want to answer it's also ok... Where did you took Scala exam? Is your company makes it for the employees or at school or may be you own initiative to learn Scala and take exam?

Comment: Nobody here would be doing any favours to the Scala community by helping people pass exams stating they're competent Scala programmers when they can't even figure a simple problem like this by themselves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recognise this homework :)

So it looks like m is a `Map`, and you don't much care about the keys in the output (perhaps you already used filterKeys by this point), so probably easiest to just pull out the values then filter - avoid all those tedious tuples and their underscores...

```
val values = m.values
val positives = values filter { _ >= 0 }
val negatives = values filter { _ < 0 }
```

Or if you prefer, this can be tidied up (and made more efficient) using the `partition` method:

```
val (positives,negatives) = m.values partition { _ >= 0 }
```

or even use the co-called "point free" style, but that might be pushing it too far:

```
val (positives,negatives) = m.values partition { 0 < }
```

You shouldn't have any problem now figuring out what to do with `positives` and `negatives`

Comment: No arguments there!  -1 to all the nay-sayers who accuse Scala of being too complicated :)

Comment: It's not a homework, but yes i was posted before, but without acceptable solution.

Comment: It supose to be a solution using only grouBy, slice, collect, sum and yield

Comment: You could always write `val positives = for(v <- m.values if v > 0) yield v`, but that's quite a bit uglier than `partition`.

Answer (score 1):

Use recursion with an inner function utilizing an accumulator:

```
def sumIt(input:List[Tuple2[Int,Int]):Tuple2[Int,Int}={
    def sum_vals(entries:List[Tuple2[Int,Int]], acc:Tuple2[Int,Int]):Tuple2[Int,Int]={
        entries match{
            case x::xs => if(x._2 < 0){ 
                    sum_vals(xs, (acc._1, acc._2+x._2))
                } 
                else{ 
                    sum_vals(xs, (acc._1+x._2, acc._2))
                }
            case Nil => acc
        }
    }
    sum_vals(input, (0,0))
}
```

Where I'm assuming you want all negative values held in the first item of the returned tuple and the negative in the second.

Edit:

FoldLeft, I need to think in terms of FoldLeft:

```
def sum_vals(left:Tuple2[Int,Int], right:Tuple2[Int,Int])={
    if(right._2 < 0){
        (left._1, left._2 + right._2)
    }
    else{
        (left._1+right._2, left._2)
    }
 }

myCollection.foldLeft((0,0))( x,y => sum_vals(x,y) )
```

Comment: Mayby you right, but I need to modify this, i thinking about yield

Comment: +1 for the solution with fold. even though it could certainly be written more concisely.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using map of maps like Map[String, Map[String, Int]] in this case solution can look like this:

```
val m = Map("hello" -> Map("a" -> 1, "b" -> -5, "c" -> 3, "d" -> -2))

val sums = m map {
  case (k, v) =>
    k -> (v.values partition (_ > 0) match {
      case (p, n) => (p.sum, n.sum)
    }).productIterator.toList
}

println(sums)
```

and the output will look like this:

```
Map(hello -> List(4, -7))
```

if you still want to use for comprehension, it can look like this:

```
for (w <- m) {
  val sums = (w._2.values.partition(_ > 0) match {
    case (p, n) => (p.sum, n.sum)
  }).productIterator.toList
}
```

(tested with Scala 2.8.1)

Comment: Wow it looks great and works like the othes solutions, but it's not it, because it's does not fit to task rules. And this is a main problem

Comment: Do you mean you want to use only 'collect' method?

Answer (score 1):

Here is solution:

```
val m = for ((k, v) <- d.groupBy(_._1.slice(0, 7))) yield k -> (for ((t, nums) <- (for ((s, l) <- (for ((date, num) <- v) yield (num, if (num > 0) 'positive else 'negative)).groupBy(_._2)) yield s -> (for ((num, _) <- l) yield num))) yield t -> nums.sum)

for ((month, nums) <- m; positive <- nums.get('positive) orElse Some(0D); negative <- nums.get('negative) orElse Some(0D)) {
  println("%7s %11.2f %11.2f %11.2f" format(month, positive, negative, positive + negative))
}
```

it gives the same result as your solution and uses only slice, groupBy, sum, yield (who needs collect :). Now another trial - you should try to understand this :) (and may be optimize)